# Completely remove sensitive information from a git message

Tags: git

I accidentally included some sensitive information in a git commit message. The actual files are all fine---it's just the content of the message itself that needs to be rolled back.

How can I purge the message so that it doesn't appear *anywhere*, including the `git reflog` history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Make a replacement commit, then manually delete or purge the unwanted reflog entries (there are two of them).  You can then run `git gc` if you like, and use `git show hash-id` to see if that threw it out.  It might not—it might still be accessible by hash ID for up to 14 days.  See below for details and additional options.

#### Description

You cannot change the existing commit.

You *can* make a *new* commit that is just like the existing commit, except for _____ (fill in the blank).

There is a handy Git built-in option to `git commit` for doing exactly that to the *most recent* commit:

```
git commit --amend
```

By default, this takes whatever is in the index right now—which, if you just made a commit that you regret making, probably still matches that commit you just made—and makes a new commit from it.  But instead of using the *current* commit as the new commit's parent, it uses the current commit's *parents* as the new commit's parents.  It also brings up your editor on the current commit's message, letting you rewrite the message.

The result is a new commit.  As always, the `git commit` command makes the current branch name point *to* the new commit just made.  But the new commit points back not to the previous tip, but to that tip's parents.  In effect, the commit you made earlier is "shoved aside":

```
...--o--o--X   <-- branch    # where X is the bad commit
```

becomes:

```
          X   [abandoned]
         /
...--o--o--N   <-- branch
```

Now, the problem is that despite being abandoned, the old commit persists in your repository for a while.  *Any* name that can find it, suffices to find it.  That includes reflog entries *and* any other branch and tag names that can reach the commit.

Since you just made the commit, presumably there are no such additional names.  That means there are only reflog entries: one for `HEAD`, and one for the branch named `branch`.

The *easiest* way to purge reflog entries is also the most (or, well, second-most) dangerous: you can run `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all`.  This tosses out all reflog entries that are not reachable from the tip of the reference in question, without looking at their ages as well.

The *best* way is probably to delete those two specific reflog entries, which are `HEAD@{1}` and `branch@{1}`, where *`branch`* is whichever branch is current.  You can run `git reflog delete HEAD@{1}` to delete the `HEAD` entry at slot 1, and similarly for the current branch's  slot-1 entry.  (You may need quotes or some such around `{1}` to protect it from your shell, depending on your shell.)

At this point there should be *no* names for the commit.  It will not show up in `git log` and will not even show up in `git reflog`.  However, one can run `git fsck --unreachable` or `git fsck --lost-found` to find unreachable objects, or if you know its raw hash ID, `git show hash-id` to see it.

Git normally leaves unreachable objects around for at least 14 days, in case they're only *temporarily* unreachable during construction.  After 14 days go by, they're probably not still needed for a Git command that has not yet finished running, so they get removed by `git gc`.  If you're *sure* there are no Git commands still running that are building things that haven't quite finished and been put on display yet, you can bypass this safety net by running `git gc --prune=all`.

There are cases where even this does not suffice, if the object has been *packed* into a protected (`.keep`) pack, but that won't apply to your situation.  In any case it's usually pointless to go to this much effort in the first place—if it doesn't show up in `git log`, most people never look any further.